# Represents the dataset in the form of a dictionary: key = (movie_title, movieId) value = array

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking for a method that would allow me to represent my dataset in the form of a dictionary: key = (movie_title, movieId) value = array

This is my DataFrame :

```
movie_title    movieId    Action   Adventure  Fantasy   Sci-Fi.  Thriller
Avatar            1        1.0       1.0        1.0      1.0       0.0
John Carter       2        1.0       1.0        0.0      1.0       0.0  
Tangled           3        0.0       1.0        1.0      0.0       0.0
```

my array is :

```
df_array = userGenreTable.as_matrix(columns=userGenreTable.columns[2:])
```

I used :

```
userGenreTable.to_dict('records')
```

But it's not what I'm looking for.

I know there is the method : `df.keys()`, `df.iterrows()`

But it's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use -

```
df.set_index(df[['movie_title','movieId']].apply(tuple,axis=1))[['Action','Adventure','Fantasy','Sci-Fi.','Thriller']].T.to_dict('list')
```

**Output**

```
{('Avatar', 1): [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0],
 ('John_Carter', 2): [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
 ('Tangled', 3): [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `set_index` and `tolist`:

```
df.set_index(['movie_title','movieId'],inplace=True)
dict(zip(df.index.tolist(),df.values.tolist()))

{('Avatar', 1): [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0],
 ('John Carter', 2): [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
 ('Tangled', 3): [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]}
```